Find spectrum of integral operator $\int_{0}^{\pi /2}K(x,y)f(y)dy$
Let $Af(x)= \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi /2}K(x,y)f(y) \mathrm dy, \quad  A: L_2[0,\pi/2] \rightarrow L_2[0, \pi/2]$
where $$K(x,y) = \begin{cases}
 \sin(x)\cos(y),& x \leq y \\
\sin(y)\cos(x),& x > y 
\end{cases}.$$
We can say: $$Af(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\sin(y)\cos(x)f(y)\mathrm dy + \int_{x}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)\cos(y)f(y)\mathrm dy.$$
And notice: $(Af)'' =  - Af - f $.
In the post Find spectrum of integral operator this means that the operator has a complete orthogonal basis of eigenfunctions, but I can't understand how to use it here.
Thanks in advance.
